# How to integrate js plugin to work with angular1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, world-of-warcraft

all World of Warcraft players knows the Wowhead.com website. This site give us its popup tooltips tool about ingame items ([Wowhead/tootips](http://www.wowhead.com/tooltips)). The name of this tool is power.js I want this tool work with angularJs but the problem is this tool update the DOM and dont really work like inspected with angularJs. Is there a way to make it work like create a custom Directive or simply turn it into a angularJs plugin ?